# Different colour of MKPinAnnotationColor dependant on time

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkpinannotationview

I am kind of new to coding, around 4 weeks experience so go easy on me.

I basically want to show a green pin on the map during specified times and when it is not these times a red pin will be shown.

Currently with the code for setting two different pins to appear at specified times is working, however I am having trouble implementing a different coloured pin for each instance.

Annotation.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Annotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

}

@property(nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end
```

Annotation.m

```
#import "Annotation.h"

@implementation Annotation
@synthesize coordinate,title,subtitle;

@end
```

MapViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface MapViewController : UITableViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKAnnotation> {


    IBOutlet UILabel *currentDate;
    NSString *todaysDate;

    MKMapView *mapView;
}

@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

MapViewController.m

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "Annotation.h"


@interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController {
}

@synthesize mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    NSLocale* locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setLocale:locale];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE HH:mm"];
    todaysDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    currentDate.text = todaysDate;

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Annotations
    NSMutableArray * locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    Annotation *myAnn;

//Area
    //Venue
    if (
        //Mon
        [todaysDate  containsString: @"Monday 17"] || [todaysDate  containsString: @"Monday 18"] ||
         //Tues
         [todaysDate  containsString: @"Tuesday 17"] || [todaysDate  containsString: @"Tuesday 18"] ||
         //Weds
         [todaysDate  containsString: @"Wednesday 17"] || [todaysDate  containsString: @"Wednesday 18"] ||
         //Thurs
         [todaysDate  containsString: @"Thursday 17"] || [todaysDate  containsString: @"Thursday 18"] ||
         //Fri
         [todaysDate  containsString: @"Friday 17"] || [todaysDate  containsString: @"Friday 18"] ||
         //Sat
         [todaysDate  containsString: @"Saturday 17"] || [todaysDate  containsString: @"Saturday 18"] ||
         //Sun
         [todaysDate  containsString: @"Sunday 17"] || [todaysDate  containsString: @"Sunday 18"]
         )
    {
        //Green
        myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
        location.latitude = 51.4;
        location.longitude = -0.1;
        myAnn.coordinate = location;
        myAnn.title = @"Venue 1";
        myAnn.subtitle = @"Subtitle 1";
        [locations addObject:myAnn];
        [self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];
        //Green
    } else {
        //Red
        myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
        location.latitude = 51.4;
        location.longitude = -0.1;
        myAnn.coordinate = location;
        myAnn.title = @"Venue 1";
        myAnn.subtitle = @"Subtitle 1";
        [locations addObject:myAnn];
        [self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];
        //Red
}

@end
```

I understand that I must use (in MapViewController.m):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
```

But then get quite lost... I have tried renaming the second pin something other than myAnn and setting MKPinAnnotationColorRed or MKPinAnnotationColorGreen dependant on the name but couldn't figure it out.

If anyone could shed some light on this I would be very grateful.

Cheers guys

Comment: Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two be able to different between the two annotations you should have a special property on the Annotation class .. e.g. a tag

```
      //Green
        myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
myAnn.tag = 0;
        location.latitude = 51.4;
        location.longitude = -0.1;
        myAnn.coordinate = location;
        myAnn.title = @"Venue 1";
        myAnn.subtitle = @"Subtitle 1";
        [locations addObject:myAnn];
        [self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];
        //Green
    } else {
        //Red
        myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
    myAnn.tag = 1;
        location.latitude = 51.4;
        location.longitude = -0.1;
        myAnn.coordinate = location;
        myAnn.title = @"Venue 1";
        myAnn.subtitle = @"Subtitle 1";
        [locations addObject:myAnn];
        [self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];
        //Red
```

}

THEN switch on the tag

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    //only handle our Annotations
    if(![annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]])
        return;

    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pizza_slice_32.png"];
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

    if((Annotation.tag == 0)) {
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    }
    else {
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    }
    return pin;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daji, this was exactly what I was looking for. I am getting "Property 'tag' not found on object of type 'Annotation'”. I presume I have to set up something in the Annotation.h and synthesize this in the Annotation.m.

Comment: @property(nonatomic, assign) X *tag;

Comment: Something like this? not sure what the X value should be.

Comment: Okay I have set @property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger tag; But I am still getting the error "Property 'tag' not found on object of type 'Annotation'", any ideas?

Comment: Oh my bad. ((Annotation*)annotation).tag :: typo ;) gotta cast the variable to the Annotation type

Comment: Ah that works!... momentarily but then crashes :-( when I // out the if(((Annotation*)annotation).tag == 0)... function then it doesn't crash

Comment: provide a minimal sample app and ill fix it for you.

Comment: Okay managed to stop it from crashing... needed to add in the following

Comment: if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) return nil;

Comment: I now added a different check for that.. `isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]` that way, we only handle our Annotation objects and ignore everything we don't know about. In general I prefer to be more concrete and that is more concrete IMHO

Answer (score -1):

In MKMapView Delegate “viewForAnnotation” you need to create a new Pin by using following method and then can change the Color accordingly.

```
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pizza_slice_32.png"];
pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
```

Comment: IMHO this doesn't answer his issue of differenting between the two annotations

Comment: If you need to check different annotations then in same delegate method you can make a check like below and then set the pin color accordingly............
                           

if(annotation.coordinate.latitude==42.0000 && annotation.coordinate.longitude==-87.65000)

Comment: in the op's case the different annotations are the same except for the time. so he needs a new property